# Running regression many times of panel data

Tags: r, loops, panel, regression

I want to run regression for my panel data. 
I have a panel data in the following format:
Column 1 has years column 2 has company name and column 3 has Equity variable

```
Year company name EQUITY
2006 A                          12
2007 A                            13
2008 A                           23
2009 A                            24
2010 A                            13
2011 A                            14
2012 A                            12
2013 A                             14
2014 A                           14
2015 A                             15
2006 B                            221
2007 B                            242
2008 B                            262
2009 B                           250
2010 B                           400
2011 B                          411
2012 B                           420
2013 B                            420
2014 B                           422
2015 B                           450
```

I have a data of 10 years for 200 companies.  I want to regress the log of equity of each company on number of years(time- 10 years ). I want only slope coefficient. 
I want my output like this:
Column 1-years column 2-company name column 3- beta values

```
Year company name slope(beta) p-value
2006 A                          beta value (assumed) 
2007  A                          "
2008 A                           " 
2009 A
2010 A
2011 A
2012 A                           "
2013 A
2014 A                          "
2015 A                         "
```

I mean slope coefficient of each comany.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see what you've tried so far so here's a solution to get you up and running. The final output you sketch out doesn't really make sense since you have a slope for each company - not for each company for each year.

Here's a base R version for running the regressions. `by` is used to split the data and then `lm` for the estimation.

```
res <- by(indata, indata$company, FUN=function(x) { coef(lm(log(EQUITY) ~ Year+0, data=x))} )
```

This results in the following output of the slopes and the output can be used for plotting or listing

```
> res

indata$company: A
[1] 0.001344837
------------------------------------------------------- 
indata$company: B
[1] 0.002896053
```

**Update**

if you want to add the slopes to the dataset for each year you can add

```
indata$slope <- res[indata$company]
```

which gives

```
> indata
   Year company EQUITY       slope
1  2006       A     12 0.001344837
2  2007       A     13 0.001344837
3  2008       A     23 0.001344837
4  2009       A     24 0.001344837
5  2010       A     13 0.001344837
6  2011       A     14 0.001344837
7  2012       A     12 0.001344837
8  2013       A     14 0.001344837
9  2014       A     14 0.001344837
10 2015       A     15 0.001344837
11 2006       B    221 0.002896053
12 2007       B    242 0.002896053
13 2008       B    262 0.002896053
14 2009       B    250 0.002896053
15 2010       B    400 0.002896053
16 2011       B    411 0.002896053
17 2012       B    420 0.002896053
18 2013       B    420 0.002896053
19 2014       B    422 0.002896053
20 2015       B    450 0.002896053
```

Comment: Thankyou.  I want same slope value each year... Is it possible we can do?

Comment: If "we" = "me" then yes. See the updated answer

Comment: Thankyou. But can i have the same valye for each year.  For eg.  If its 12.34 for company A.  Then for each year 2006-2015...this value (12.34) come.

Comment: That's what the slope does

Comment: Yes,  but can i have that same value in each year....  Instead if dragging/copying for each company...  As my data set require the same.

Comment: Show an exact example of what you are after

Comment: I am using mobile app, so i am not able to type my example properly. Will post correct example performa soon through computer. Thankyou in advance.